# Manually trigger freeze/resume lifecycle events

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, browser

Is it possible to manually trigger the `freeze` and `resume` [lifecycle events](https://developer.chrome.com/articles/page-lifecycle-api/) in Chrome?

They're very useful events, but very difficult to test and debug!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can manually create events and then trigger them, like so:

```
// Create a custom 'freeze' event 
let freezeEvent = new Event('freeze');

// Trigger the custom 'freeze' event on the document 
document.dispatchEvent(freezeEvent);
```

Answer (score -1):

Triggering the freeze and resume lifecycle events in Chrome manually isn't straightforward since they're tied to specific browser behaviors related to background tab freezing to conserve resources.

These events, freeze and resume, are part of the Page Lifecycle API. While you can simulate tab freezing by manually throttling CPU or memory usage through developer tools, directly triggering these events is not supported or exposed for manual invocation.

For testing purposes, you can try simulating background tab freezing by following these steps:

Throttling CPU: Use the Performance panel in Chrome DevTools to throttle CPU. Emulate a busy tab and switch to another tab to see how Chrome handles freezing and resuming.

Throttling Network: Emulate network conditions or slow connections. This might not directly simulate freeze and resume, but it can impact how a tab behaves when it's in the background.

Memory Throttling: You can simulate memory pressure by loading a resource-intensive page or script. Check the behavior of your page when memory usage is high, potentially causing other tabs to freeze.

Emulate Background Tabs: Open your site in multiple tabs, perform actions in one tab, and observe how Chrome handles background tabs, especially if they're using significant resources.

Comment: Wow. ChatGPT is in the house

Comment: [Temporary policy: Generative AI (e.g., ChatGPT) is banned](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831/11107541)